# What can I use instead of std::move()?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, rvalue-reference, move-semantics

I'm using a C++ compiler with the C++0x specification, and want to make my move constructor for a String class that wraps around a std::wstring.

```
class String {
public:
    String(String&& str) : mData(std::move(str.mData)) {
    }

private:
    std::wstring mData;
};
```

In Visual Studio, this works flawlessly.  In Xcode, `std::move()` is not available.

Comment: What compiler is this that supports rvalue references and not `std::move`?

Comment: @Prætorian : Apple LLVM compiler 3.0

Comment: C++0x = C++11. If you mean a compiler that doesn’t support `std::move`, write *that*, don’t invent a non-existing distinction that’s going to baffle everybody.

Comment: By the way, tip of trunk clang should know `move` – would it be possible for you to upgrade your version?

Comment: @KonradRudolph : I didn't intend to baffle anyone - nor did I think I was inventing something.  Enlightening me without condescension would have been a more suitable response, thanks.

Comment: @PhoenixX_2 : It is not condescending to point out that your question is needlessly confusing.

Comment: @ildjarn : No, but accusing me of inventing distinctions when it wasn't intended (clearly) isn't the most thoughtful thing.  Anyway, as per your request to reduce baffling people, I've rephrased the answered question.

Comment: @PhoenixX_2 : Not everyone is a native english speaker, and not every word is perfect. Don't be so sensitive. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn And not everyone is capable of asking a question that suits your "perfect" vision of a question. The question is clear enough to be answered.

Comment: @MuhamedCicak : Yes, I have no problem with the question now post-edit; the edit that I prompted improved the quality of the question so I don't know who you're white-knighting for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::move` simply casts its argument to an rvalue reference. You could write your own version:

```
template<class T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&
move( T&& arg ) noexcept
{
  return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>( arg );
}
```

Comment: `remove_reference` isn't defined. I did however look how it was done in STL - thanks for the tip!

Comment: @PhoenixX_2 std::move and std::remove_reference are part of the standard library. Since the compiler already knows about rvalue references you should simply use a C++11 standard library rather than try to implement your own `move()`. I'm guessing that you were using libstdc++, and you should look into switching to libc++.

Comment: @bames53 : I'm not very familiar with Xcode, and the only options I see, I have tried. Wrapping my own move() worked flawlessly.

Comment: @PhoenixX_2: If you can't get `std::move` to work, then your installed C++11 standard library is *broken*. I suggest you work on fixing your standard library installation rather than implementing your own `std::move`. Otherwise you'll just have more problems in the future. I wouldn't trust `std::wstring` from it.

Comment: @NicolBolas : Things seem to be working fine. There's no particular library I installed separate from Xcode. I am unable to update to the latest compiler and libraries (which likely has more of the specification complete) until I update to the latest Mac OS X, which I'm not willing to do at this point.

Comment: @Phoenix - The problem is that if the standard library you use doesn't know about `move`, I bet `wstring` will copy the string anyway. It doesn't help that *you* try to move if the library is not.

Comment: @BoPersson : Hm, you're absolutely right, I didn't think of it that way.

Comment: @bames53 Some embedded platforms support C++, but don't have the STL. So it's fairly safe to assume that if you don't have `std::move`, you don't have `std::remove_reference`